# Next date of the purchased customers

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID   Date    Zone Group  destination  start        end                      sec    step   unit

1 2020-01-25 Zone1 GP1     D1         2020-01-25 08:18   2020-01-25 08:22   240      E     18

1 2020-01-25 Zone3 GP3     D1         2020-01-25 14:18   2020-01-25 14:22   198      P     50

1 2020-01-26 Zone3  GP3    D1         2020-01-26 14:18   2020-01-26 14:22   298      P     50

1 2020-01-27 Zone4 GP4     D1         2020-01-27 20:04   2020-01-27 20:09   283      D     55

1 2020-01-27 Zone3 GP3     D1         2020-01-27 08:18   2020-01-27 08:22   740      E     22

1 2020-01-27 Zone4 GP4     D1         2020-01-27 10:43   2020-01-27 10:57   853      p     289

2 2020-03-13 Zone1 GP1     D1         2020-03-13 08:08   2020-03-13 08:11   201      N     555 

2 2020-03-13 Zone2 Gp2     D1         2020-03-13 06:27   2020-03-13 06:40   767      E     789

2 2020-03-13 Zone3  GP3    D1         2020-03-13 21:02   2020-03-13 21:09   409      P     552

2 2020-03-15 Zone4 GP4     D1         2020-03-15 21:09   2020-03-15 21:10    78      P     253
```

Here I need customer next purchase date please see the below output,
customer  1 had purchased(Step=p) on dates are  2020-01-25,2020-01-26,2020-01-27
I need next purchases date where step=p that means on row two the values are 2020-01-26 and row 3the values are 2020-01-27 and row 6 the values are should be NULL because there is no purchase after 2020-01-27 date.

OUTPUT

```
ID Date       Zone  Group destination start             end    sec step unit NextPurchase_date  

1 2020-01-25  Zone1 GP1  D1   2020-01-25 08:18 2020-01-25 08:22  240  E 18  NULL

1 2020-01-25 Zone3 GP3   D1  2020-01-25 14:18 2020-01-25 14:22  98   P 50  2020-01-06  

1 2020-01-26 Zone3 GP3   D1  2020-01-26 14:18 2020-01-26 14:22  298  P 50  2020-01-27

1 2020-01-27 Zone4 GP4   D1 2020-01-27 20:04  2020-01-27 20:09  283  D 55  NULL

1 2020-01-27 Zone3 GP3   D1 2020-01-27 08:18  2020-01-27 08:22 740   E 22  NULL

1 2020-01-27 Zone4 GP4   D1 2020-01-27 10:43  2020-01-27 10:57 853   p 289  NULL

2 2020-03-13 Zone1 GP1   D1  2020-03-13 08:08 2020-03-13 08:11 201   N 555  NULL


2 2020-03-13 Zone2 Gp2   D1 2020-03-13 06:27 2020-03-13 06:40 767    E  789  NULL

2 2020-03-13 Zone3 GP3   D1 2020-03-13 21:02 2020-03-13 21:09 409    P  552  2020-03-15

2 2020-03-15 Zone4 GP4   D1 2020-03-15 21:09 2020-03-15 21:10 78     P 253 NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when step = 'P'
             then convert(date, lead(start) over (partition by id, step order by start))
        end) as next_purchase_date
from t;
```